# Dijit not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Hi all I'm trying to use dijit from the dojo library and trying to use the Calendar component. I followed the code as it is in the online documentation but it just doesn't seem to work. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    />
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        .claro table.dijitCalendarContainer { margin: 25px auto; } #formatted
        { text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>

<body class=" claro ">
    <div dojoType="dijit._Calendar" onChange="dojo.byId('formatted').innerHTML=dojo.date.locale.format(arguments[0], {formatLength: 'full', selector:'date'})">
    </div>
    <p id="formatted">
    </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // loads the optimized dijit layer
    dojo.require("dijit._Calendar");
</script>
</html>
```

Using firebug it shows the following error:

> Could not load 'dijit._Calendar'; last
>   tried '../dijit/_Calendar.js'

Please can anyone help me on this. I really want to make this work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your tree appears to have been changed, or at least you relocated the copy of dojo.js from the standard distribution.  You should include dojo as "dojo/dojo.js"  It will then use that reference to find relative urls in the tree, like ../dijit/_Calendar.js

Comment: i tried this but still not working. i get following error in console: 
failed loading dojo/../dijit/form/_FormWidget.js with error: Error: Could not load 'dojo.window'; last tried './window.js'

Comment: are these paths valid? You should have a dijit directory as a peer of dojo, and dojo/window.js and dijit/form/_FormWidget.js should exist in the tree... either some of your tree is missing or perhaps that initial path in the script tag still isn't right?  You might want to check firebug net panel for the 404's which should give you the entire paths.  Match that up against your filesystem.